# How to limit query to a specified number of entries but for each parameter separately?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a messages table, where there are messages between users. Users are identified by numbers. In the code below I download last 100 messages for all the users.

But how to download max 30 messages for each separate user "To", using just mysql command?

Current code:

```
$this->db->select('To, From, Date, Content');  
$this->db->order_by('Date', 'DESC');
$this->db->limit(100);
$query = $this->db->get('Messages');
```

Comment: For the purposes of brevity, I suggest you adjust the parameters (4 users, latest 3 messages for each, say), and see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: OK, so let's pretend that we have 4 users, and we need to download 3 last messages for each of the users. Using Limit in the code below would download 3 messages, but for all the users combined.

Comment: Great. Now see the link.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/803f2/2

Comment: Thanks for the progress report.